# Connecting to MariaDB Galera Cluster takes a long time

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have a 5 node production MariaDb 10.3 Galera cluster that has been running for well over a year. In the last few weeks, it now takes more than 10 seconds for any client to establish a database connection. Our code runs in python, however even using a desktop client takes between 10 and 13 seconds to connect. Once connected, everything is fine. We have a similar cluster running in another site that I checked and connections take about 1 second or less. There are less than 10 active clients connected at any given time and there's nothing extra with regards to load. I'm not even sure where to start looking...

Comment: Even 1 second seems long.  Are you using any sort of "proxy" between the clients and the cluster?  Is the client geographically near the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the logs via terminal `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep mysql` I could see dns resolve errors every few seconds. Adding **skip-name-resolve** to the mysql.cnf file and restarting the nodes, this issue went away. The reason it started happening up was due to a downstream router blocking internet access to the subnet. This is a closed system but does have internet access via a GRE tunnel.